# Keep the connection between app and NodeJS alive for 2 minutes

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax

I am trying to make a jQuery ajax call to a NodeJS server, the server will then POLL a another end-point for a maximum of 2 minutes.

Unfortunately just as the server is done POLLING and about to respond to the jQuery ajax post the connection is killed.

How can I keep the connection alive for 2 minutes for this route only not for every route. This is my AJAX post right now:

```
$.ajax({
    url:  $(this).attr("action"),
    type: 'POST',
    data: formdata,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    beforeSend: function(request) {
        request.setRequestHeader("Keep-Alive", 'timeout=121, max=100')
    },
    success: function (res) {        
        if (res.status === 200) {
            Materialize.toast(res.msg, 4000, 'green')
        }
        else {
            Materialize.toast(res.msg, 4000, 'red')
        }
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        Materialize.toast(error, 4000, 'red')
    }
})
```

When I examine the request header, 'Keep-Alive' is not being set, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser controls this time out so there is nothing you can do about it. I think they're all around the 1-2 minute mark (which I think is very fair), obviously, the browser cannot keep a socket open for longer as it could cause performance issues, memory leaks etc. You can override them locally but that's not going to do any good for anyone but yourself - as default users will have the default `KeepAliveTimeout`.

What you should really be thinking of is a better solution to achieve what you want here. A long-running task which keeps a socket open for that long is just wrong.

I would think about doing an initial API call which triggers the process to start which then just returns a success response to the UI to say "yes this has starting processing..". Then on your API once it is complete fire an event to the UI using `websockets`. There are plenty of `npm` packages out there to support this.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/websocket

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws

A solution that you are proposing could not survive in the real world so changing your thinking in how this could be achieved is the best way to resolve this. Might not be the answer you were hoping for but overall changing this will greatly improve everything about your solution.

Good luck.

Comment: Hi Thanks, I appreciate the info! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can either use [web sockets](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io) or [server side events (SSE)](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/) to meet your requirement. Instead of increasing the `KeepAliveTimeout`time.